# How do i colour a BufferedImage/ Image in java?

Tags: java

Sorry, if I asked a question that doesn't make sense, basically i just need a code snippet and possibly an explanation on how to colour in Images in java. (The images are greyscale)

Comment: It's hard for me to guess what you're asking here. What have you tried? Where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: Well, I have a class which loads the image i want e.g.-
    public static final BufferedImage[][] car =          Image.cut("/res/entity/carsheet.png", 32, 32);

But i want the car i have loaded to be a different colour than it's greyscale image

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, I'm guessing you want to "tint" the image? If so, see this:

[Applying a tint to an image in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4248104/applying-a-tint-to-an-image-in-java)

If you're asking how to restore the color the image would have been if it was made in color, don't even attempt it.