# Java : How to tint this PNG programmatically?

Tags: java, image, image-processing, png

Within the frame of a chess applet, I have a few sets of such greyscale/black & white (not sure) :

Is there any way to give a color tint to a PNG picture via Java Code ? Tried to google the matter and didn't find anything really matching what I'm looking for.

For the following piece for example, I'd like to give it white/yellow tint for the White player, and a flavour of black for the Black player. The idea of setting the color dynamically is to tweak themes at runtime.

[image]

Comment: Possible dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4248104/applying-a-tint-to-an-image-in-java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be a lot simpler to give your program translucent images (PNG) which are plain coloured (plain or gradient) in the colours you want, and have a certain % of transparency (you can do that in photoshop/illustrator in 1min).

Then programmatically merge the tint image (preserving transparency) with the other image underneath.

Check this SO post for how to merge two images:
[Merging two images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2318020/merging-two-images)

Answer (score 0):

I found this on StackOverflow. It's pretty good explanation, so I won't bore you with any additional details :) Hope that helps: [Applying a tint to an image in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4248104/applying-a-tint-to-an-image-in-java)